# SignalR usage in Azure Function App and publishing on portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-signalr

When I am using Azure SignalR version 1.0.2 with latest Azure Function version 3.0.3, the function app runs fine locally, but when published (Zip Deploy) on Azure Portal, I am getting the following error:

[image: Error]

The Nuget Packages in my project are:

[image: Nuget Packages]

The function app runs locally as expected but on the Azure portal I get the following error.
How to resolve this issue?

One thing I found help with was that on portal if I change the host.json from:

```
Original:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

After Change:

```
{
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

Then it works exactly fine, but this change adds a manual step to my deployment which I dont want, currently my deployment is through azure pipelines

Answer (score 0):

[Extension Bundles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles) are primarily suited for local development which allows you to not have the .NET Core SDK installed, especially in cases where you are developing functions using a non-C# language.

Considering that you are using Visual Studio for development, you could probably do away with the extension bundle in your `host.json`